# Enable Put Command on lightTPD

Tags: lighttpd, put

How can I enable using of PUT method in lightpd? I searched for this issue like 2 hours and did not get any reasonable result, the only thiing which was helpful is that I should use "mod_webdav" somehow to enable Put method.
So if you know how to do it, please help.
Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to configure `mod_webdav` to implement the HTTP PUT method.  This is a good place to start http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModWebDAV